# Fixed number of character lines per <p> without using monotype fonts, is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I need to split a big chunk of text into paragraphs of the same size, with the exact same number of string lines to keep them uniforms, i'm currently doing it with php with the following code.

```
        function arrangeText(){
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :  the_post();

                    $content = strtolower(get_the_content());
                    $content = trim(strip_tags($content));
                    $post_len = strlen($content);
                    $segmentCont = 1; 
                    $auxOffset = 0; 
                    $auxOffset2 = 0;
                    $limit = 896; 
                    $limitTotal = 0;

                    while($limitTotal<$post_len){

                            if($segmentCont==2) {
                                $limit = 943;
                            }

                            $segmentCont++;
                            $limitTotal = $limitTotal + $limit;
                            if($limitTotal<$post_len)
                             { $auxOffset = strpos($content," ",$limitTotal);}
                            else 
                             { $auxOffset = $post_len;}
                            $post_segment = trim(substr($content,$auxOffset2,$auxOffset-$auxOffset2));
                            $auxOffset2 = $auxOffset;
                            echo_segment($post_segment);
                    }

                    endwhile;                       
                    endif;
                }
```

### This actually works but even though im counting each character, some characters may take up to three  character spaces, so my paragraphs get different number of lines, or the last line is sliced in half, if i use a monotypefont everything goes smoothly, but my client wants a specific font, and i've been trying all sort of things with no luck, so i come to you the big guys for help. The only thing i can imagine to solve this is a very complex script to get the width of each character im echoing and add that value to a counting variable each time, and do a conditional (inside a loop i guess) to check if the total width of the characters exceeds the total width of my paragraph if so slice it before the last " "(white space) it founds(preventing the code to cut words in half), but i have no idea if this is possible with php, js, jquery or anything that can help me out on a website, im sure there is an easy way to do what i'm trying here but maybe im just not smart enough, so pls help me out =).

Edit 1: My bad, the mono-spaced font won't do the trick either, they were getting cut and overflowing below my p tags ( overflow:hidden ) and i though they were working until i read the text, so i guess that even that they are mono-spaced, their character sizes are different too.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is just `text-align: justify`?

Comment: @Amber Haha that's the first thing I thought of when I read the title

Comment: Lol, if it were a simple answer like i'll be relief, but the text-align: justify doesn't work like the photoshop version that it adjust the last line no matter if you have 3 characters only, i know there should be an easy way to do this, i can't think i'm creating the first site with dynamic and horizontal blocks of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to measure widths of characters and create a "dictionary".
You can tweak it to return relative values (lets say `w = 1`, `i = 0.5` so it will be more flexible).

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw4AV/

```
var chars = ["a", "b", "c", "i", "w"];
var widths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
{
    var span = $("<span>").text(chars[i]);
    $("body").append(span);
    widths.push(span.width());
}
alert(widths);
​
```

Comment: Excellent, it works, from here i can come up with something, thanks =)

Comment: There was an issue with this code, it was not possible to get a white space width using this and i was very confused about why my code wasn't perfect until i noticed it. Since i'm using justify on the paragraph, the white space vary in its width so i had to try something else, it was possible to measure the white spaces outside the loop, so i placed each character inside a span and then i measured each one of them and worked perfectly, i'll update my question to post the code later, thanks again strah.

Answer (score 1):

I think a really good idea would be to have a dictionary of Key,Value being Character,Size and then as you iterate through instead of just each character counting as one they count as "Size' (fast lookup with the dictionary).  However, this may not work if the characters don't exactly equal a multiple of the other character's size.

What do you think about that?

Comment: Yep that's kinda what i was saying above, but is it possible with any of these languages to get the width in pixels of any characters, or i would have to manually create a dictionary for each font-family i wan't to test?, and btw i would have no idea where to find these info, maybe manually measuring each character (of a specific css font size) with photoshop? sounds like a pain in the... any concretes ideas on that?.... btw thanks for answering dude, i really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to determine the width of a character using php you could do that using the [`imagettftext()`](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function. Create an white image or something and draw a single letter in black color on it. Then use the [`imagecolorat()`](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) function to determine the black pixel which is the positioned the most right.

Comment: That gives me an idea but its way too complicated too, i'll look into it, thanks.